# Using Jquery to hide all other classes while only one is active

Tags: jquery

I'm a little new to this Jquery thing. What im trying to do is use links to toggle classes, which hold elements of a page. what i need to do is use a script to call up elements for one link, but hide all the other elements associated with other links, so that a person can click the link only once to get the elements for that page, and have everything else hidden. I have been using the toggleclass function in jquery, but that requires the user to click once to activate the elements for one class, but then click again to remove them before they can click another link.

Is this even possible? I've found some javascript that seems like it does what i need it to, but I don't understand it enough to implement it.

i'd prefer it to be jquery, because I seem to have a decent grasp of that, but not on javascript as a whole. (I'm teaching myself all types of tricks through trial and error)

Comment: You should put an example to clarify your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the exact situation is for you, but depending on your structure, you can always use `.siblings()`.

For an example, with the following setup:

```html
<div id="mydiv">
    <p id="p1">Something1</p>
    <p id="p2">Something2</p>
    <p id="p3">Something3</p>
</div>
```

Your jQuery would then look something like:

```js
$("#p1").show().siblings().hide();
```

This assumes that you have `display:hide;` set in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` to iterate over elements.  So, inside an `each()`, just do a `.hide()` on the elements.

Hiding an element would look like this:

```
$('#id).hide();
```

each documentation [is here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: Is it also possible to use .show and .hide events if I specify which by using id="" in the types of things I want to hide?

Comment: Yes, you can use show and hide events, but it can become out of hand in a hurry if you're trying to show and hide a huge quantity of things.  Alternatively, you could park elements in a container div and just hide the div, which will hide everything inside as well.

Comment: thats basically what im trying to do, and I've tried it, and its working, i just have to get the timing on them right. its a little bit of code, about a page long, but its easy for  me to keep track of that way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Basic and Simple Solution

sample html:

```
<ul id="controls">
   <li><button data-value="#a" type="button">show a</button></li>
   <li><button data-value="#b" type="button">show b</button></li>
</ul>

<div id="elements">
   <div id="a" class="element"></div>
   <div id="b" class="element"></div>
</div>
```

script: 
this get all buttons inside controls ID and call a function called toggleElements with the value assigned to the data-value attribute of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#controls button').click(function() {
      toggleElements($(this).attr('data-value'))
   });
});
```

the toggleElements function check if target is/has something and if it does, it hides all elements and show the target one.

```
function toggleElements(target) {
   if (target && $(target).length >0) { 
      $('element').hide(); 
      $(target).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Bart's answer but I'm not sure really what OP was trying to describe in his question.
OP, can you give us some sample code to paint the problem picture better? I imagined OP wanting to do something like this.

```
// Your HTML something like...
// Note: They can be any elements, divs, span, whatever, give element an id.

<a id="alpha">Toggle type one</a>
<a id="bravo">Toggle type two</a>

<div class="typeOne"></div>
<div class="typeOne"></div>
<div class="typeTwo"></div>
<div class="typeTwo"></div>

// Your jQuery something like this:

$('#alpha').click(function() {
    $('.typeOne').show();
    $('.typeTwo').hide();
}

$('#bravo').click(function() {
    $('.typeTwo').show();
    $('.typeOne').hide();
}
```

Basically this would make it so that all elements are visible at first. When they click link id="alpha" then it shows all elements of class="typeOne" and hides elements of class="typeTwo". When you click on link id="bravo", it hides typeOne and shows typeTwo...

Answer (score 0):

Simplest menu what i have created below:

// Jquery Code //

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('ul li', this).click(function (){
            $('#' + $(this).text()).css({display: 'block'}).siblings().hide()
        });
    });
```

// HTML Code //

```
    <div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Product</li>
        <li>FAQ</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="Home">First DIV</div>
        <div id="Product">Second DIV</div>
        <div id="FAQ">Third DIV</div>
        <div id="Contact">Fourth DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// CSS //

```
ul { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
li { float: left; width: auto; padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px; background: #999; color: #fff; list-style-type: none;  border: 1px solid #333; }
#content div { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; clear: both; border-top: 1px solid white; display: none;}
#content div#item4{ border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
#main { border: 1px solid #000; float: left; }
```

Comment: This might lead into the right direction, but does not directly refer to the actual question (`class` not `id` used, keeping track of current state), does it?